# RequiredFieldValidators issue in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am in the process of adding RequiredFieldValidators into my form and just tested it on the web and received this error

**Error**

```
WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).
```

I added the solution which was this in the web.config file:

```
<appsettings>     <add value="None" key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode"></add>   </appsettings>
```

But that prompted this error

**Error**

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
```

This last error is saying something is wrong with the solution I inputted above.. Has anyone else ever run into this and have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you have set `targetFramework` to 4.5 . The full config should look like this.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"></add>
  </appSettings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

If this key value is set to "None" [default], the ASP.NET application will use the pre-4.5 behavior (JavaScript inline in the pages) for client-side validation logic. If this key value is set to "WebForms", ASP.NET uses HTML5 data-attributes and late bound JavaScript from an added script reference for client-side validation logic.

**Reminder**: `<appSettings>` parent in the web.Config file should be the root element, that is `<configuration>`.

Helpful links - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/465613/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.unobtrusivevalidationmode.aspx -- This says it a feature of v4.5, you should have to specify `targetFramework = 4.5` in cofig to make it work.